# sql server update with dateadd changing format

Tags: sql-server, dateadd

```
update calendar
set duedate = DATEADD(mm,1,duedate)
from calendar as t1
inner join events as t2
on t1.person = t2.[person]
where t2.catastrophy ='FamilyDeath'
```

I want to postpone a `duedate` by one month if there is a family death.

My dates are in the format of 04/30/2015. I run the above query, and it will take the date and change it to May 30 201. If I try to run it again I get an error stating:

> "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value."

Comment: What's the datatype of the `duedate` column?

Comment: the data type is char(10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think because the type is char(10), you're getting a conversion you don't want. You're converting from CHAR to datetime, then just storing that as a CHAR. When you do the dateadd, try putting it back into the right CHAR format like this:

```
set duedate = convert(char(10),dateadd(mm,1,dueDate),101)
```

CONVERT allows you to specify a format, and 101 is "mm/dd/yyyy"

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx